# Python "ImportError: cannot import name 'pnoise1' from 'noise'"

Tags: python, noise

I have been trying to use the noise module in Python for a game I was making. I am on the Mac OS, and I used `pip3 install noise` to download the module. I uninstalled and reinstalled it multiple times, without the wheel library, and with, as it recommended. The noise module itself downloads fine, but every time I try to import `pnoise` from it, I get an ImportError.

Just straight up importing noise (`import noise`) gives me no error, it just prints a string of numbers to my console. Also, downloading and running the module in a virtual environment works, so it must be something on my computer or OS.

Code: `from noise import pnoise1`

Error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'pnoise1' from 'noise'`

I have looked for a while for a solution, but nothing has seemed to help, it just doesn't work. The only information I have found is that this may be a file problem, but I haven't found out how to fix it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
I ended up figuring it out. I was importing a file by the same name instead of the library. Thanks for the help, everyone!

Comment: Do you get an error if you do `import noise`?

Comment: No @chc, that works fine.

Comment: I tried myself and everything is working. Try to do it in a virtual environment: `cd project_dir`, `python3 -m venv venv`, `source venv/bin/activate`, `pip install noise`, `python`, `>>> from noise import pnoise1` (https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/)

Comment: @chc I tried a virtual environment and it raised no errors... This must be something on my computer then I assume...?

Comment: Do this: `cd`, `pip freeze > pip.txt`, `pip uninstall -r pip.txt`, `rm pip.txt`. Now you have no external package installed in your system Python. From now on every time you create a Python project add to its directory a new virtual environment and install there the external dependencies you need

Answer (score 0):

To me it works ok. Have you installed it correctly via pip/pip3?

Comment: I have it installed correctly, and it works in a virtual environment. It must be something on my computer or OS that I causing it to raise an error.

Comment: Ok, I saw your other comment, I'm glad you have resolved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring it out, I was importing a file of mine instead of the library. Thanks for the help!